# Is it grammatically wrong if "collected" is deleted from the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Squids **collected** from North coast ate fish, whereas this food item was absent in the stomachs of squids collected from South coast.

Is it grammatically wrong if collected is deleted from the sentence?

Comment: Do the squids live their whole lives in either the North or South coast? If not, *collected* changes the meaning. Otherwise, probably not, unless *collected* describes some activity mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *collected* can be removed from the sentence. 
There are some other grammatical issues that you might want to address though. There should be a definite article before both *north coast* and *south coast*. And why is the first letter of the second *squids* capitalized? Your sentence should be:

> Squids collected from **the** north coast ate fish, whereas this food item was absent in the stomachs of **s**quids collected from **the** south coast.

Also, I am not sure about the tense of **ate** there but there isn't enough context for me to decide if it's right or not.